# configuring asp.net web.config session

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, web-config

I'm trying to increase the `Session` timeout without modifying code. Does `sessionState` time in `web.config` override the default 20 minute IIS session time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS session timeout value is for classic `.asp` pages only. For ASP.NET applications, only the web.config specified timeout value applies. That means the Web.Config session settings will override over IIS settings for `.aspx pages`.

Secondly in the ASP.NET/Framework 2.0 you get an ASP.NET tab on IIS where you can manage the config file settings. Those do have an affect on ASP.NET but not on classic ASP Applications.

Answer (score 0):

you can write session timeout in  Session_Start Event in global.asax file